# Invalid option: gem check -t mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I'm trying to run the unit tests on the mail gem, but I get the following. I've done this in accordance with the gem manual here http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10

```
> gem check -t mail
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: -t
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like this option was removed from rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

These are now suggested by RubyGems as mentioned on the site below:

gem install rubygems-test
gem test my_favorite_gem

[Gem Testers](http://test.rubygems.org/)